# Ubuntu 15.04 Linux 4.0 Python error while updating, Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: 14.04, apt, python, dpkg

While running autoremove command or update or even for any install commands I'm getting following error.

> My System is Ubuntu 15.04 Upgraded from 14.04 and Linux kernel is 4.00 upgraded from 3.19. And I have installed python 3.4.3 and I'm able to use python3 by `python` command.

Please help me as its completely in bad state. TIA

```
vivek@Wisdom:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.19.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-16-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/89.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 208 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 391390 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.19.0-16-generic (3.19.0-16.16) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-16-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.19.0-16-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic

run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-16-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-16-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.19.0-16-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 3.19.0-16-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.19.0-16-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-16-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-040000-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-040000-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-21-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-20-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-16-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-image-3.19.0-16-generic (3.19.0-16.16) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/prerm.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms 3.19.0-16-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
dkms: removing: open-vm-tools 9.4.6 (3.19.0-16-generic) (x86_64)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  open-vm-tools
Version: 9.4.6
Kernel:  3.19.0-16-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vmhgfs.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.19.0-16-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vmxnet.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.19.0-16-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.
dkms: removing: vboxhost 4.3.28 (3.19.0-16-generic) (x86_64)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  vboxhost
Version: 4.3.28
Kernel:  3.19.0-16-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxdrv.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.19.0-16-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetflt.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.19.0-16-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetadp.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.19.0-16-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxpci.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.19.0-16-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-16-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-16-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-16-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-040000-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-040000-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-21-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-20-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Setting up python-appindicator (12.10.1+15.04.20141110-0ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-appindicator (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-keyring (4.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-keyring (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-lazr.uri (1.0.3-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-lazr.uri (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-simplejson (3.6.5-1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-simplejson (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-wadllib:
 python-wadllib depends on python-lazr.uri; however:
  Package python-lazr.uri is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-wadllib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-oauth (1.0.1-4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-oauth (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-lazr.restfulclient:
 python-lazr.restfulclient depends on python-lazr.uri; however:
  Package python-lazr.uri is not configured yet.
 python-lazr.restfulclient depends on python-simplejson; however:
  Package python-simplejson is not configured yet.
 python-lazr.restfulclient depends on python-wadllib (>= 1.1.4); however:
  Package python-wadllib is not configured yet.
 python-lazr.restfulclient depends on python-oauth; however:
  Package python-oauth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-lazr.restfulclient (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-launchpadlib:
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-keyring (>= 0.5); however:
  Package python-keyring is not configured yet.
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-lazr.restfulclient (>= 0.11.2); however:
  Package python-lazr.restfulclient is not configured yet.
 python-launchpadlib dependsNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                         on python-lazr.uri (>= 1.0.2-4~); however:
  Package python-lazr.uri is not configured yet.
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-oauth; however:
  Package python-oauth is not configured yet.
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-simplejson; however:
  Package python-simplejson is not configured yet.
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-wadllib; however:
  Package python-wadllib is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-launchpadlib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-secretstorage (2.1.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-secretstorage (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: error processing package python-aptdaemon (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:
 python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on python-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu3); however:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                Package python-aptdaemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-center:
 software-center depends on python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
 software-center depends on python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets; however:
  Package python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of y-ppa-manager:
 y-ppa-manager depends on python-launchpadlib; however:
  Package python-launchpadlib is not configured yet.
 y-ppa-manager depends on python-appindicator; however:
  Package python-appindicator is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package y-ppa-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-appindicator
 python-keyring
 python-lazr.uri
 python-simplejson
 python-wadllib
 python-oauth
 python-lazr.restfulclient
 python-launchpadlib
 python-secretstorage
 python-aptdaemon
 python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
 software-center
 y-ppa-manager

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**UPDATE**
As suggested I tried all the three steps

1.First Step generating same error as I have posted for `sudo apt-get autoremove`

2.For Second alternative installing from `.deb` is generating following error

```
vivek@Wisdom:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i python-configparser_3.3.0r2-2_all.deb
(Reading database ... 386190 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python-configparser_3.3.0r2-2_all.deb ...
File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
except (IOError, OSError), e:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
except (IOError, OSError), e:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing archive python-configparser_3.3.0r2-2_all.deb (--install):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
python-configparser_3.3.0r2-2_all.deb
```

3. For third alternative I downloaded `compressed file` extracted and ran the command again I got error.

   ```
   vivek@Wisdom:~/Downloads$ cd configparser-3.3.0r2 && sudo python setup.py install
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "setup.py", line 12, in <module>
   from setuptools import setup, find_packages
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
   import distutils.core
     File "/usr/Python-3.4.3/Lib/distutils/core.py", line 18, in <module>
   from distutils.config import PyPIRCCommand
     File "/usr/Python-3.4.3/Lib/distutils/config.py", line 7, in <module>
   from configparser import ConfigParser
     File "/home/vivek/Downloads/configparser-3.3.0r2/configparser.py", line 397
   _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")
                                        ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   ```

I can't understand whats going on with my os.
Thanks for help.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python` as a first step maybe?

Comment: @ByteCommander  Same Error again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Complete Solution of the problem is

- I installed python 3.4.3 from python.org as a tar file after extraction I symlink to python, where it was already available in ubuntu 14.04 as python3.
- Actually some packages on ubuntu 14.04 were dependent on python 2.7 so the symlink to python 3.4.3 was causing all problems.

How to solve it ..

```
`Just re symlink your python 2.7 to python and --reinstall python-configparser`
```

thats what helped me.

Thanks All.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the first error is a missing module:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

Try to install `python-configparser` with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-configparser
```

If it does not work with `apt-get` try to download the [deb package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/all/python-configparser/download) and install it manually with:

```
sudo dpkg -i python-configparser_3.3.0r2-2_all.deb
```

As a third option (thanks @Byte Commander), you can install configparser from source:

- download and extract the version available in vivid from pypi: [configparser-3.3.0r2.tar.gz](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/configparser/configparser-3.3.0r2.tar.gz)
- Install with the following command:

  ```
  cd configparser-3.3.0r2 && sudo python setup.py install
  ```

Then try again to install a package with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-launchpadlib
```

Comment: Python modules can also be installed with `pip` or `easy_install`, if the package _python-setuptools_ is available: `pip install ConfigParser` or `easy_install ConfigParser` should do the trick, I guess.

Comment: @ByteCommander that's a good idea, if `pip` is already installed otherwise `dpkg` would I guess fail to install `python-pip`.

Comment: @ByteCommander I've updated my answer to install `configparser` from source. Thanks for the suggestion