# Problem installing elementary desktop on Ubuntu

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, configuration, elementary

I was trying to install elementary desktop on Ubuntu but I get the following error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libecore-dev:
 libecore-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev; however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libecore-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libefreet-dev:
 libefreet-dev depends on libecore-dev (>= 1.8.6); however:
  Package libecore-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libefreet-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libemotion-dev:
 libemotion-dev depends on libecore-dev (>= 1.8.6); however:
  Package libecore-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libemotion-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libeeze-dev:
 libeeze-dev depends on libecore-dev (>= 1.8.6); however:
  Package libecore-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libeeze-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libelementary-dev:
 libelementary-dev depends on libecore-dev (>= 1.8.0); however:
  Package libecore-dev is not configured yet.
 libelementary-dev depends on libefreet-dev (>= 1.8.0); however:
  Package libefreet-dev is not configured yet.
 libelementary-dev depends on libemotion-dev (>= 1.8.0); however:
  Package libemotion-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libelementary-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libethumb-dev:
 libethumb-dev depends on libecore-dev (>= 1.8.6); however:
  Package libecore-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libethumb-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libeio-dev:
 libeio-dev depends on libecore-dev (>= 1.8.6); however:
  Package libecore-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libeio-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev:
 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev; however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgstreamer0.10-dev:
 libgstreamer0.10-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev; however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgstreamer0.10-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libedje-dev:
 libedje-dev depends on libecore-dev (>= 1.8.6); however:
  Package libecore-dev is not configured yet.
 libedje-dev depends on libeio-dev (>= 1.8.6); however:
  Package libeio-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libedje-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libecore-dev
 libefreet-dev
 libemotion-dev
 libeeze-dev
 libelementary-dev
 libethumb-dev
 libeio-dev
 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
 libgstreamer0.10-dev
 libedje-dev
```

Comment: What did you run to generate that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 15.04 Linux 4.0 Python error while updating, Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/646553/ubuntu-15-04-linux-4-0-python-error-while-updating-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-re)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install all the dipendecies before install a package. You can try to install elementary with `apt-get install -f`.
The option `-f` resolve dependencies and fix broken packages.

Comment: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: What was the command you wrote that returned this error?

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f